# Plot orbit of three bodies using rk4

Tags: python, scipy, runge-kutta, orbital-mechanics

I have been trying to plot the trajectories of three particles using the RK4 method. I haven't been able to produce an array of results over the time period as it brings up the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\Local\Runge-Kutta 4 Code.py", line 65, in <module>
    solution.step()

  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py", line 170, in step
    raise RuntimeError("Attempt to step on a failed or finished "

RuntimeError: Attempt to step on a failed or finished solver.
```

I suspect that there is a problem with the initial "y_0" value that I have but I could be wrong.
Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as scipy

from scipy import integrate
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import savetxt

# Physical constants
mass_vector = np.array([1, 1, 1])

r_vec_1 = np.array([0, 0])
v_vec_1 = np.array([-np.sqrt(2), -np.sqrt(2)])

r_vec_2 = np.array([-1, 0])
v_vec_2 = np.array([np.sqrt(2) / 2, np.sqrt(2) / 2])

r_vec_3 = np.array([1, 0])
v_vec_3 = np.array([np.sqrt(2) / 2, np.sqrt(2) / 2])


#Initial x acceleration ODE's
def x1_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    #G can be omitted for scale purposes (should not be compared with realistic data)
    return ((mass_vector[1]*(y[4]-y[0])/((y[0]-y[4])**2 + (y[1]-y[5])**2)**(3/2)) +
            (mass_vector[2]*(y[8]-y[0])/((y[0]-y[8])**2 + (y[1]-y[9])**2)**(3/2)))
def x2_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    return ((mass_vector[0]*(y[0]-y[4])/((y[4]-y[0])**2 + (y[5]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) +
            (mass_vector[2]*(y[8]-y[4])/((y[4]-y[8])**2 + (y[5]-y[9])**2)**(3/2)))
def x3_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    return ((mass_vector[0]*(y[0]-y[8])/((y[8]-y[0])**2 + (y[9]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) +
            (mass_vector[1]*(y[4]-y[8])/((y[8]-y[4])**2 + (y[9]-y[5])**2)**(3/2)))
#Initial y acceleration ODE's
def y1_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    return ((mass_vector[1]*(y[5]-y[1])/((y[0]-y[4])**2 + (y[1]-y[5]**2)**(3/2))) +
            (mass_vector[2]*(y[9]-y[1])/((y[0]-y[8])**2 + (y[1]-y[9])**2)**(3/2)))
def y2_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    return ((mass_vector[0]*(y[1]-y[5])/((y[4]-y[0])**2 + (y[5]-y[1]**2)**(3/2))) +
            (mass_vector[2]*(y[9]-y[5])/((y[4]-y[8])**2 + (y[5]-y[9])**2)**(3/2)))
def y3_double_dot(y, mass_vector):
    return ((mass_vector[0]*(y[1]-y[9])/((y[8]-y[0])**2 + (y[9]-y[1]**2)**(3/2))) +
             (mass_vector[1]*(y[5]-y[9])/((y[8]-y[4])**2 + (y[9]-y[5])**2)**(3/2)))

#This is my X(t) at time zero
y_0 = np.concatenate((r_vec_1, v_vec_1, r_vec_2, v_vec_2, r_vec_3, v_vec_3))
y = y_0

#This is my F(X) at time zero
def fun(t,y):
    return np.array([y[2], y[3], x1_double_dot(y, mass_vector), y1_double_dot(y, mass_vector),
              y[6], y[7], x2_double_dot(y, mass_vector), y2_double_dot(y, mass_vector),
              y[10], y[11], x3_double_dot(y, mass_vector), y3_double_dot(y, mass_vector)])

# collect data
t_values = []
y_values = []

#Time start, step, and finish point
t0,tf,t_step = 0, 2, 0.1
nsteps = int((tf - t0)/t_step)

solution = integrate.RK45(fun, t0, y_0, tf, first_step=t_step)

#The loop for running the Runge-Kutta method over some time period.
for step in range(nsteps):
    solution.step()
    y_values.append(solution.y[0])
    # break loop after modeling is finished
    if solution.status == 'finished':
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I condensed the setup and derivatives computation to

```python
masses = [1,1,1]
r1,v1 = [ 0,0], [-2**0.5,-2**0.5]
r2,v2 = [-1,0], [0.5**0.5, 0.5**0.5]
r3,v3 = [ 1,0], [0.5**0.5, 0.5**0.5]
G = 1

def odesys(t,u):
    def force(a): return G*a/sum(a**2)**1.5
    r1,v1,r2,v2,r3,v3 = u.reshape([-1,2])
    m1,m2,m3 = masses
    f12, f13, f23 = force(r1-r2), force(r1-r3), force(r2-r3)
    a1,a2,a3 = -m2*f12-m3*f13, m1*f12-m3*f23, m1*f13+m2*f23
    return np.concatenate([v1,a1,v2,a2,v3,a3])
```

Then the execution I essentially copied your code, just adding some options that are nice for the graph

```
from scipy import integrate

#Time start, step, and finish point
t0,tf,t_step = 0, 2, 0.1
nsteps = int((tf - t0)/t_step)
u0 = np.concatenate([r1,v1,r2,v2,r3,v3])

solution = integrate.RK45(odesys, t0, u0, tf, first_step=0.2*t_step, max_step=t_step)

# collect data
t_values = [t0]
u_values = [u0]

#The loop for running the Runge-Kutta method over some time period.
for step in range(nsteps):
    solution.step()
    t_values.append(solution.t)
    u_values.append(solution.y)
    # break loop after modeling is finished
    if solution.status == 'finished':
        break
```

There were no errors reported, and the solution plots as

[image: plot of the diverging orbits]

My scipy version is 1.4.1.

The plot is obtained via

```
u = np.asarray(u_values).T
# x1,y1 = u[0], u[1],  x2,y2 = u[4],u[5]
plt.plot(u[0],u[1],'-o',lw=1, ms=3, label="body 1")
plt.plot(u[4],u[5],'-x',lw=1, ms=3, label="body 2")
plt.plot(u[8],u[9],'-s',lw=1, ms=3, label="body 3")
```

Instead of, e.g., `u[4]` after the transformation of the view of the data in `u_values` one could also have used `u_values[:][4]` using the original result data structure.

---

With changed data so that the center-of-mass is largely constant, and the first body small to the other two, and an increased gravity constant

```
masses = [0.01, 1, 1]
r1,v1 = [ 0,0], [-2**0.5,-2**0.5]
r2,v2 = [-1,0], [ 0.5**0.5, 0.5**0.5]
r3,v3 = [ 1,0], [-0.5**0.5,-0.5**0.5]
G = 4
```

The resulting dynamic is

[image: sequence of orbit segments]

Comment: As "u_values" is a list of arrays, how would one extract the data to plot the values for each particle? (i.e. I would think: plt.plot(u_values[???],u_values[???]) then repeat using plt.point for the other particles)

Comment: Yes, but you have to regard that a list of numpy arrays is not a 2-dimensional numpy array. So you have to use separate addressing of the dimensions, `u_values[:][0]` etc. I've added my variant where the 2-dim. numpy array is constructed and transposed.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: It seems that if the mass of the first particle is changed to 0, the method does not seem to work. Also, if inputting 0 for either of the other two masses does not result in the expected two body orbits. What can be done to prevent this?

Comment: As a guideline, a circular orbit `R*exp(i*w*t)` relative to the center-of-mass with radius `R` will have period `T=2*pi/w` where `w=R^-1.5`. This gives a tangential velocity `v=R*w=R^-0.5`. This is seemingly the case in your data. But, body 2 and 3 start in parallel, with a relative velocity of zero. So with `m1=0` they just fall into each other, which leads to a singularity. Change the signs on one of the velocities so that the center-of-mass is at rest and you get elliptical orbits, with body 1 doing several swing-by's and flying away in the end.

Comment: That last was not completely true, with these changes the orbits are hyperbolical. I had to set the gravity constant to 4 to get elliptical orbits.

Comment: Making the velocities equal in opposite directions seems to produce the elliptic orbit that we are discussing. However, because the mass of the 1st particle is zero, why does it perform these swing-by's, why does it not just fly off in a straight line to infinity in the direction of it's velocity vector?

Comment: Because it is still influenced by the gravity fields of the other bodies, it is like an umpowered space probe in that regard.